# How to get total count of query result on large dataset?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas-search

I've a collection of 10 million docs on which I ran queries with $search from atlas-search,
I want to display the total count of the result but it takes to much time to return the result.

I've tried this :-

```
{
  '$search': {
    // index: 'default',
    'text': {
      'query': query,
      // path: {
      //   'wildcard': '*'
      // }
      'path': ['title', 'description']
    }
  },
},
// {
//   $count: "total"
// },
// {
//   $group:{_id: null,Total:{$sum:1}} 
//   } 
// {
//   $limit: 80
// },
// {
//  $facet:{"groupedByColors":[{$unwind: "$color"},{$group:{_id:"$color","count":{$sum:1}}},{$project: { "colorfield": "$_id", "count": 1 }},{$sort:{"count":-1}},{$limit: 10}]}
// }
// {
//   $facet:{"groupedByColors":[{$unwind: "$color"},{$group:{_id:"$color","count":{$sum:1}}},{$project: { "colorfield": "$_id", "count": 1 }},{$limit: 10}]}
//  }
]
```

Comment: try to run a count with pipeline without skip/limit and then add it: 
```const countPipeline = [...pipelineWithoutSkipLimit, { $count: 'count' }];
const count = db.collection.aggregate(countPipeline);
const finalPipeline = [...pipelineWithoutSkipLimit, { $skip }, { $limit }];```

Comment: I didn't get this how this is working?